# How to fix the footer in UIViewController using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to iOS programming. I have to fix the footer in the `UIViewController`. I know how to fix the sticky footer in `UITableViewController`.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix the footer in `UIViewController`?

Comment: Check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_toolbar.htm

Answer (score 0):

uiviewcontroller does not have header or footer view.you need to create view in its subview and set with it bottom layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Using Auto Layouts : Add View to Bottom of the View and Set Constraint to Left , Right and Bottom So Footer is Ready at Bottom Irrespective on Any Screen Size .